# Where are stored the assets on an Usergrid server?

Tags: apigee, usergrid

I want to know where the assets (files) are stored on an Usergrid server and how to change their location on the filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research it appears that by default they are stored in `/tmp/usergrid`

This is not optimal at all. It is possible to change the location by editing this file `/stack/rest/src/main/resources/usergrid-rest-context.xml`

From

```
<bean id="binaryStore" class="org.apache.usergrid.services.assets.data.LocalFileBinaryStore">
    <property name="reposLocation" value="${usergrid.temp.files}"/>
</bean>
```

To

```
<bean id="binaryStore" class="org.apache.usergrid.services.assets.data.LocalFileBinaryStore">
    <property name="reposLocation" value="/<customcation>"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

I put my static assets in a *virtual* path with my server.xml:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/static/files" path="/static" />
```